# need some help on c++ ifstream

Tags: c++

I have some error on int main. I'm tring to read txt.file from computer and display that on screen but I can't figure out how. Mainly on the ifstream part and for loop display part. Can you guys help me on this ?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class WeatherReport
{
    WeatherReport friend monthEnd(WeatherReport, WeatherReport);

private:

    int dayofMonth;
    int highTemp;
    int lowTemp;
    double amoutRain;
    double amoutSnow;

public:

    WeatherReport(int Day = 0);
    void setValues(int, int, int, double, double);
    void displayReport();
};

void WeatherReport::setValues(int dom, int ht, int lt, double ar, double as)
{
    dayofMonth = dom;
    highTemp = ht;
    lowTemp = lt;
    amoutRain = ar;
    amoutSnow = as;
}

int main()
{
    const int DAYS = 30;
    WeatherReport day[DAYS];
    WeatherReport summary;

    int i = 0;

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("Students.txt");
    if (!inFile.good())
        cout << "File not opended!" << endl;
    else
    {
        while (inFile >> dom >> ht >> lt >> ar >> as)
        {
            day[i].setValues(dom, ht, lt, ar, as);
            i++;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();

    for (int i = 0, i < DAYS, i++)
    {
        DAYS[i].display();
        //read one line of data from the file
        //pass the data to setValues to initiialize the object
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `I have some error on int main` Please include the error in your question.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: There are **simple** syntactical errors, learn basic C++ then start coding, please don't copy paste codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has numerous typos. Please slow down and carefully consider what you are writing.

First off, you haven't declared any local variables to extract into:

```
int dom, ht, lt; double ar, as;
while (inFile >> dom >> ht >> lt >> ar >> as)
```

You have commas where you require semi-colons:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DAYS; i++)
```

`DAYS[i].display()` is just wrong. It should be:

```
day[i].displayReport();
```

---

`if (!inFile.good())` is not necessary. `if (!inFile)` suffices.

`system("PAUSE")` is considered bad practice by some. For starters, it isn't portable.

Comment: oh I see. thank you for that. some of them were easy mistakes...I was rushing through...my bad on this. There are this error called too few arguments in function call. How can I fix this one?